# Solana Private key with 87 characters

Tags: solana, wallet, phantom-wallet

Hi I am building an account on phantom wallet but the weird thing is that the private key that is generated is of 87 characters and its base is also 65 where as the old wallet account of phantom that i have a private key length 88 and base is 64. The biggest problem is that when i am using this 87 length private key so it throws error that bad size private key.

I tired using this thing

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs58

But it didnt helped me out